# What is the difference between Privacy Protection and Privacy and Business Protection in GoDaddy

Tags: domain-registration, godaddy

I am planning to buy a domain from GoDaddy. I do not need any hosting/builder/email (I am planning to host on Amazon EC2), all I need is just to own a domain.

But when I selected the domain of my choice, I see the following options:

[image]

which actually looks the same to me. So what are the differences between these two options?

I have also seen [not so nice](http://www.authormedia.com/6-reasons-authors-should-avoid-godaddy/) reviews about Godaddy, but based on my understanding, they are more about hosting, than domain registration. Am I correct?

Comment: Got me. I use goDaddy and did when I was a webhost so I can tell you they are an excellent company. You may be surprised by my next recommendation, but I have had good luck here too. Call 'em! Ask. I know you will get a clear and precise answer. Surprised?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try to contact them and most probably this is a right thing to do.

Comment: I am curious. Let us know what you find out.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is GoDaddy's page that fully documents the differences](https://www.godaddy.com/domainaddon/private-registration.aspx).   Business protection offers four additional bullet points:

- Prevents accidental loss of domain due to expired credit card
- Deadbolt Transfer Protection
- Certified Domain Seal proves to visitors that your site's ownership is valid
- Get an online business card in the WhoIs directory